# Difference in prediction values for a binary classifier in ML.net and Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ml.net

I was comparing results between the same model generated and used between two frameworks (Ml.net and tensorflow/keras) independently.

These are the steps in followed in getting the results:

1. Train Model in Keras save as .h5 format.
2. Convert to .pb model to use in ML.net, as ml.net currently uses tensorflow graphs and not saved model format.

Now for the same two images, the prediction value should be the same. As the model is the same. The difference being the underlying framework.

I could find only bits and pieces regarding why this occours. I am running both the programs with same underlying hardware and software configurations.

Is the underlying cause the difference in framework?

The image prediction scores for example  images :

**ml.net : 0.9929248 Fail
keras/tensorflow : 0.99635077 Fail**

The difference is minute, but being deterministic  irrespective of platform is a feature that I  am looking for.

Comment: What version of Tensorflow did you use?

Comment: Microsoft.ML.TensorFlow : 1.5.2, 
Tensorflow :  2.2

Comment: It could be the differences in Tensorflow versions. ML.NET currently uses Tensorflow.NET which is still using a version of Tensroflow that's in  version 1. There's currently [a PR](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/pull/5404) to update it's usage of Tensorflow.NET to 0.20 which is using Tensorflow version 2.

Comment: thanks for that Information. I did use tensorflow 1.15 to test it again, but the same result. I wonder is it due to some differences in how both the libraries handle image input.

Comment: Thanks for checking that! That's probably true on the image input. It may be worthwhile to put this as an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/new) to the repo to see if the team has any more information.